# Time period in group by sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, group-by

I am developing a book reservation system for a library.
In the table of the Reservations there are the fields:
**id_reservation, id_user, id_book, datetime.**

I want to count the reservations that completed in the mornings and the reservations completed in the evenings assuming that morning is between 10:00 and 15:00 and evening is between 15:00 and 21:00.

I need something like :
Select count(id_reservation) as total_reservations from reservations group by **time_period**

Any help **how to distinquish the two time periods** in order to use them in **GROUP BY**?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '15:00:00' THEN 'Morning' 
             WHEN TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '15:00:00' AND '21:00:00' THEN 'Evening' 
             ELSE 'NA'
        END) AS time_period, 
       COUNT(id_reservation) AS total_reservations 
FROM reservations 
GROUP BY time_period;
```